# Can someone explain to me how this recursion function is working?

Tags: c++, recursion

```
int prod(int a, int b) {

if (a == 0 || b == 0) {

    return 0;
}

else {
    
    return a + prod(a, b - 1);  
}   
}
```

It looks simple but I can't understand why it works? How does it return the correct product if it eventually returns 0? I'd appreciate if someone could walk me through the process of this, thanks.

Comment: Multiplication is just repeated addition. Write out on paper what happens with `prod(2, 2)`.

Comment: Try printing values of a, b and return value before return.

Comment: The 100% correct and utterly useless answer to most "Can someone explain?" questions is "Yes." Instead you should state what you think and why and turn the question into, "Am I right?" This shows you've invested in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Well most peoples will dislike it but ill try to explain it to you.

So lets write random numbers for example a =3 b=4 to be different.

So the program doesn't know how it is for real  3+prod(3,4) just simple
and what is he going to do well hes going to call next function like 3+prod(3,3) //because u decrement 1; and again program doesn't really know how it is and will keep calling itself until 3 reach 0 and will return 0 to next function.

I will show u how it looks like now

- a = 3 b=4

```
3+ (3,4) //it checks if b or a ==0
3+ (3,3) //it checks if b or a ==0
3+ (3,2)//it checks if b or a ==0
3+ (3,2)//it checks if b or a ==0
3 + (3,1)//it checks if b or a ==0
3+ (3,0) //it checks if b or a ==0
and last one ya  a==0
```

So condition is correct so

- it return 3 to function which called it  in this case  return prod 3+(3,1)
- called   return prod 3+(3,0)
- so it will from prod 3+(3,0) to 3+(3,1) and what value it will return?
- of course 0
- so it will keep returning

```
3+ prod(3,1) ==0 // 0 is returned arleady and program knows this value
3+ prod(3,2) == 3+3
3+ prod(3,3) ==3+6
3+ prod(3,4) ==3+9
```

so finally u have 12.

Answer (score 0):

Well the function obeys a simple maths rule which is :
a*b = a + a*(b-1) and a*(b-1) = a + a*(b-2) and etc
So the function goes through a product by decomposing a*b to a*(b-1) until it reaches the value 0 where it stops.

Answer (score 0):

If b is 0 it returns 0 (because if you multiply something with 0 you get 0).

Is b is positive it returns `a+prod(a,b-1);` Yes the innermost call prod(a,0) will return 0 the one which called it prod(a,1) will return a and so on until the original prod(a,b) will return a+a+...+a=a*b

Note that it only works if b is not negative. Also the check if a==0 is irrelevant. (It makes the code a bit faster if a==0 but in this code performance is not priority).